# Shutdown of GrapheneDB’s Heroku Add-on on January 14, 2021

Tags: node.js, heroku, neo4j, database-migration, graphenedb

Graphenedb is closing their free hobby tier on Heroku. My application is too small to warrant the minimum subscription of $50 per month they're requiring going forward. Does anyone have any experience using an alternative graph database with heroku that would be easy to migrate to?